# Any way to unit test Android's ICU library?

Tags: android, testing, icu

So I want to make use of the [ICU implementation for Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/package-summary) and for example the formatters are things that should be definitely unit tested, but since it is included in the Android framework I'm left with just instrumented tests.

Is there a way to unit test these formatters?